# Lost UUID on RAID devices after reboot

Tags: raid, mdadm, uuid

I'm looking for a bit of help trying to figure out why I can not reassemble a RAID after reboot. I have tried:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

My previous /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf is as follows. The RAID of interest is md1 at the bottom there. This was a RAID0 made out of 4 nvme drives attached on a an ASUS Hyper M.2 x16 card.

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
#ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=73abfd2e:9332c4dd:6bdf75fc:e457fac6 name=functionalgenomics.server:0

# This configuration was auto-generated on Fri, 27 Sep 2019 11:59:21 -0700 by mkconf
#ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=functionalgenomics.server:0 UUID=73abfd2e:9332c4dd:6bdf75fc:e457fac6
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=functionalgenomics.server:0 UUID=73abfd2e:9332c4dd:6bdf75fc:e457fac6
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=functionalgenomics:1 UUID=86a1939b:26fac733:9006b919:36e6f30e
```

But after reboot the last line is no longer there. System looks like so with lsblk:

```
walter@functionalgenomics:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME      SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0   161.4M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
loop1    99.2M squashfs          loop   /snap/core/10859
loop2     2.5M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-calculator/826
loop3     2.2M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
loop4    55.5M squashfs          loop   /snap/core18/1988
loop5     276K squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-characters/570
loop6    99.2M squashfs          loop   /snap/core/10908
loop7     2.5M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-calculator/884
loop8     548K squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-logs/103
loop9    55.4M squashfs          loop   /snap/core18/1944
loop10    276K squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-characters/550
loop11   64.4M squashfs          loop   /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
loop12    2.2M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-system-monitor/157
loop13   64.8M squashfs          loop   /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop14    956K squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-logs/100
loop15  162.9M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop16  217.9M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop17    219M squashfs          loop   /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
sda       9.1T linux_raid_member disk   
└─md0    18.2T ext4              raid10 /data
sdb       9.1T linux_raid_member disk   
└─md0    18.2T ext4              raid10 /data
sdc       9.1T linux_raid_member disk   
└─md0    18.2T ext4              raid10 /data
sdd       9.1T linux_raid_member disk   
└─md0    18.2T ext4              raid10 /data
sde       477G                   disk   
├─sde1    512M vfat              part   /boot/efi
└─sde2  476.4G ext4              part   /
nvme0n1 931.5G                   disk   
nvme1n1 931.5G                   disk   
nvme2n1 931.5G                   disk   
nvme3n1 931.5G                   disk
```

Its those last 4 nvme drives that were in a RAID0.

I've tried manually reassembling with mdadm by UUID:

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 --uuid 86a1939b:26fac733:9006b919:36e6f30e
```

Since none of this was working, I inspected the disks with blkid:

```
$blkid
/dev/sde2: UUID="622cb66b-07b8-4b3e-bf66-47e328d108b5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2bbad625-4e76-44f2-984e-82f137ca5e94"
/dev/sdb: UUID="73abfd2e-9332-c4dd-6bdf-75fce457fac6" UUID_SUB="2addace1-4dcf-83a1-efca-06efbe945214" LABEL="functionalgenomics.server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sda: UUID="73abfd2e-9332-c4dd-6bdf-75fce457fac6" UUID_SUB="99d89efb-611f-31e0-e18a-15d24884c89e" LABEL="functionalgenomics.server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="bc67c382-2764-490a-b4d7-0a90090d21a5" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme1n1: PTUUID="f84c4a99-5f3b-4c24-a28f-67986efd5fc9" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme2n1: PTUUID="5051655f-2d62-484a-83e4-222ace832a02" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme3n1: PTUUID="113b2827-7ae1-48af-8c81-d6a0b8e2315b" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdd: UUID="73abfd2e-9332-c4dd-6bdf-75fce457fac6" UUID_SUB="62827ba3-e4e5-67f7-b966-0f644790452a" LABEL="functionalgenomics.server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sde1: UUID="16F7-B5D4" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="e94f401a-a861-492a-bc75-dc67efdaa5a3"
/dev/md0: UUID="f06692a8-6db3-4a19-864b-4aaedd14ed8a" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc: UUID="73abfd2e-9332-c4dd-6bdf-75fce457fac6" UUID_SUB="f808cf3c-ea1b-773e-e77c-372de7714b8c" LABEL="functionalgenomics.server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
```

It appears that the devices have lost their UUID to the RAID? I've shutdown, unplugged, replugged and rebooted. No luck.

fdisk -l gives (deleting all the loop* since its long:

```
fdisk -l


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BC67C382-2764-490A-B4D7-0A90090D21A5


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F84C4A99-5F3B-4C24-A28F-67986EFD5FC9


Disk /dev/nvme2n1: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5051655F-2D62-484A-83E4-222ACE832A02


Disk /dev/nvme3n1: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 113B2827-7AE1-48AF-8C81-D6A0B8E2315B


Disk /dev/sda: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 51A8D887-C792-4353-B2BF-1724213AAEC1

Device       Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sde1     2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sde2  1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md0: 18.2 TiB, 20001394262016 bytes, 39065223168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
```

Any thoughts on how to recover this, hopefully without lost data would be very appreciated. Thanks!

[Edit/update]

I tried madam --examine for these:

```
$ mdadm --examine /dev/nvme*
mdadm: cannot open /dev/nvme0: Invalid argument
/dev/nvme0n1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953525167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
mdadm: cannot open /dev/nvme1: Invalid argument
/dev/nvme1n1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953525167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
mdadm: cannot open /dev/nvme2: Invalid argument
/dev/nvme2n1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953525167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
mdadm: cannot open /dev/nvme3: Invalid argument
/dev/nvme3n1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953525167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

Also:

```
$ mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose

mdadm: No super block found on /dev/nvme3n1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme3n1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/nvme2n1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme2n1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/nvme0n1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme0n1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/nvme1n1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme1n1
```

Comment: Any thoughts on brute forcing the old UUID on to the disks?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12858/how-to-change-filesystem-uuid-2-same-uuid

Comment: Your md0 RAID members are configured without using partition table. I assume md1 was configured the same way. But the result of "fdisk -l" shows that each nvme drive has now an empty GPT partition table. I suppose that some tool (OS installer, patritioning app...) has initialized these drivies with an empty GPT table, and thus has overwritten RAID superblock, and destroyed this RAID. Is that posiible? Did you run for example Windows installer between reboots?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I didn't run anything between reboots. I do not believe there was any tool/app involved here. This is typically used as a server accessed only through command line.  Could this somehow be the result of poor configuring choices at the outset?